How can I make certain annotations display in wfdb?
For example, the picture shows the annotations 'N' and 'V', but I don't need the display of 'N', I only need 'V'. Is there any way to do this? The files were taken from this database.
I'm an absolute beginner in this library, but I've been reading the documentation and couldn't find anything that would help solve my problem.
And that's my code.
import wfdb

def show_graph(rec_name):
    record = wfdb.rdrecord(
        record_name=rec_name,
        sampto=4500
    )

    anno = wfdb.rdann(
        record_name=rec_name, 
        extension='atr',
        sampto=4500
    )

    wfdb.plot_items(
        signal=record.p_signal,
        ann_samp=[anno.sample, anno.sample],
        ann_sym=[anno.symbol, anno.symbol],
        sharex=True,
        sharey=True
    )

show_graph('sudden-cardiac-death-holter-database-1.0.0/31')


Usage:
#@title Muat sebuah *instance of SinyalEKG*

signals, fields = wfdb.rdsamp('workspace/dataset/qt-database-1.0.0/sel16420') # sinyal
ann = wfdb.rdann('workspace/dataset/qt-database-1.0.0/sel16420', 'pu0') # anotasi

signal = ECGSignal(signals[:,0], ann.sample, ann.symbol, ann.fs, field_unit=fields['units'][0], source = 'QTDB', record_name = ann.record_name, sig_name=fields['sig_name'][0], extension=ann.extension)

signal.plot(start_idx=int(1*signal.ann_fs),
            stop_idx=int(3.6*signal.ann_fs)
          )

Output:

Class
# Signal Processing
import wfdb
from scipy.signal import resample_poly

# Visualization
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.font_manager import FontProperties

# Serializer
import _pickle as pickle

# Path
import os
import glob

# Data Science
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import math

#@title Mendefinisikan Kelas SinyalEKG

class ECGSignal():

  def __init__(self, signal_sample : np.ndarray, ann_sample : list, ann_symbol : list, ann_fs : int, sec_start : int = 0, field_unit : str = 'y', source : str ='null', record_name : str = 'null', sig_name: str = 'null', extension : str ='null'):

    # metadata
    self.field_unit = field_unit
    self.source = source
    self.record_name = record_name
    self.sig_name = sig_name
    self.extension = extension

    self.signal_sample = signal_sample
    self.ann_sample = np.array(ann_sample, dtype=int)
    self.ann_symbol = ann_symbol
    self.ann_fs = ann_fs # yang ini original frequency sampling, jangan dikucak. Pakek ini kalo nak tau originalnyo

    self.fs = self.ann_fs # nah fs yang ini bolehlah berubah-ubah

    self.timestep = 1/self.fs

    # Pemetaan simbol jenis gelombang ke angka.
    self.__label_map = { # https://github.com/MIT-LCP/wfdb-python/blob/main/wfdb/io/annotation.py
      'B': 0,
      'p': 1,
      'N': 2,
      't': 3
    }

    # mapping untuk keperluan display plot
    self.__display_label_map = {
      self.__label_map['B']: ('gray', 'baseline'),
      self.__label_map['p']: ('orange', 'p-wave'),
      self.__label_map['N']: ('green', 'qrs-wave'),
      self.__label_map['t']: ('purple', 't-wave'),
    }

    # tipe data kolom untuk Pandas DataFrame
    self.__dtype_dict = {'seconds': np.float64, 'amplitude': np.float64, 'wave_label': np.int64, 'bound_label': np.int64}

    # Amplitudo dan label direstruktur jadi satu array.
    self.signal_arr = np.zeros((signal_sample.shape[0], 4), dtype=np.float64) # (panjang_sinyal, (detik, amplitudo, segmen_label, bound))
    self.__isi_kolom_waktu(sec_start)
    self.__isi_kolom_amplitudo()
    self.__isi_kolom_label()
    self.__isi_kolom_bound()
    # self.__isi_kolom_peak()
    self.to_df()

  def __get_p_onset_indices(self):
    '''
    Ini dipakek untuk algoritma nyari indeks p-onset dengan ngecek array sinyal saat ini, jadi robust dengan data yang sudah di resample!!!
    '''
    return np.where((self.signal_arr[:, 2].astype(int) == self.__label_map['p']) & (self.signal_arr[:, 3].astype(int) == 1))[0] # jika jenis label sinyak adalah p (24) dan jika jenis label bound adalah onset (1)

  def __get_nearest_p_onset_index(self, p_onset_index=0):
    p_onset_indices = self.__get_p_onset_indices()
    ann_sample_resampled = self.ann_sample
    returned = np.where(np.abs(self.ann_sample - p_onset_indices[p_onset_index]) <= 1)[0]
    return np.where(np.abs(self.ann_sample - p_onset_indices[p_onset_index]) <= 1)[0][0]

  def __rewind_arr_to_40ms(self, arr):
    return arr - int(self.fs * (0.04))

  def __pad_array(self, arr, target_length=512):
    '''
    paper dan aku sama sama menggunakan zero padding.
    Aku melakukan padding kiri kanan yang seimbang, artinya beatnya berada ditengah.
    Sementara itu, paper melakukan padding kiri sebanyak 16 zeros, sisanya padding kanan, artinya yang paper lebih condong ke kiri beatnya.
    '''

    # Calculate the number of zeros to be added
    pad_len = target_length - len(arr)
    if pad_len <= 0:
        return arr[:target_length]

    # Calculate the number of zeros to be added on the left and right
    pad_left = pad_len // 2
    # pad_left = 16 # uncomment baris ini untuk menggunakan padding rujukan paper
    pad_right = pad_len - pad_left

    # Pad the array
    padded_arr = np.pad(arr, (pad_left, pad_right), 'constant', constant_values=(0, 0))

    return padded_arr, pad_left

  def __isi_kolom_waktu(self, start=0):
    self.signal_arr[:, 0] = np.linspace(start=start, stop=(start+(self.signal_arr.shape[0]/self.fs)), num=self.signal_arr.shape[0])

  def __isi_kolom_amplitudo(self):
    self.signal_arr[:, 1] = np.array(self.signal_sample)

  def __isi_kolom_label(self):
    for i in range(len(self.ann_symbol)): # iterasi yang digunakan untuk memberi masked label dan menandai mana puncak.
      try:
        sym = self.ann_symbol[i] # ambil symbol sekarang

        if sym == '(':
          neigh_sym, neigh_idx = self.ann_symbol[i+1], self.ann_sample[i+1] # (simbol jenis wave setelah onset, index jenis wave sebelum offset)
          arange = np.arange(self.ann_sample[i], neigh_idx+1, dtype=int) # mengambil list of indices dari onset ke peak
        elif sym == ')':
          neigh_sym, neigh_idx = self.ann_symbol[i-1], self.ann_sample[i-1] # (simbol jenis wave sebelum onset, index jenis wave sebelum offset)
          arange = np.arange(neigh_idx, self.ann_sample[i]+1, dtype=int) # mengambil list of indices dari peak ke offset
        else:
          continue # jika bukan daripada batas atas atau batas bawah, maka lewati

        self.signal_arr[:,2][arange] = np.full(arange.shape, self.__label_map[neigh_sym]) # memberi masked label
        # self.signal_arr[:,4][neigh_idx] = self.signal_arr[:,4][neigh_idx].astype(int) | True << 1 # menandai puncak (ditandai pada bit ke-1) NOTE: Tidak digunakan lagi
      except KeyError:
        # Kadang ado outlier cak ini, di mano DAK KATEK PEAK, nah itu continue bae jangan dilabeli ['(', 'p', ')', '(', ')', '(', 't', ')', '(', 'p', ')']
        continue

  def __isi_kolom_bound(self):
    for label in self.__label_map.values(): # iterasi yang digunakan untuk menandai atas dan batas bawah
      masked_label = self.signal_arr[:,2].astype(int) # ambil array label yang termasked
      filtered = np.where(masked_label == label, 1, 0) # atur mask yang difilter ke 1 jika cocok dengan label, jika tidak maka 0.
      padded = np.concatenate(([0], filtered, [0])) # lakukan padding atas dan padding bawah untuk mencegah error
      diffed = np.diff(padded) # lakukan operasi diferensial untuk menemukan batas atas dan batas bawah
      onset_indices = np.where(diffed == 1)[0] # hasil pengurangan berupa 1 menandakan onset
      offset_indices = np.where(diffed == -1)[0] - 1 # hasil pengurangan berupa -1 menandakan offset, kemudian dikurangkan 1 agar sesuai dengan indeks
      self.signal_arr[:,3][onset_indices] = self.signal_arr[:,3][onset_indices].astype(int) | True << 0 # menandai onset (ditandai pada bit ke-0)
      self.signal_arr[:,3][offset_indices] = self.signal_arr[:,3][offset_indices].astype(int) | True << 1 # menandai offset (ditandai pada bit ke-1)

  def to_df(self):
    self.df = pd.DataFrame(self.signal_arr, columns=self.__dtype_dict.keys()).astype(self.__dtype_dict)
    self.df['seconds'] *= pd.Timedelta(1, 's')
    self.df.set_index('seconds', drop=True, inplace=True)
    return self.df

  def resample(self, new_frequency_sampling=500):
    time_start = self.signal_arr[0,0]
    self.signal_sample = resample_poly(self.signal_sample, new_frequency_sampling, self.fs) # resample amplitudo
    self.ann_sample = (self.ann_sample * (new_frequency_sampling/self.fs)).astype(int) # resample label yaitu indeks dari simbol-simbol
    self.fs = new_frequency_sampling
    self.timestep = 1/self.fs
    self.signal_arr = np.zeros((self.signal_sample.shape[0], 4), dtype=np.float64) # (panjang_sinyal, (detik, amplitudo, segmen_label, bound))
    self.__isi_kolom_waktu(time_start)
    self.__isi_kolom_amplitudo()
    self.__isi_kolom_label()
    self.__isi_kolom_bound()
    # self.__isi_kolom_peak()
    self.to_df() # update DataFrame

  def plot(self, start_idx=0, stop_idx=None):

    if stop_idx is None: # kalo dak diisi, yo diisi coy
      stop_idx = start_idx + int(len(self.df.index)) - 1
      if int(len(self.df.index)) > self.fs: # kalo banyak nian, mendeng tampelke satu detik be
        stop_idx = start_idx + self.fs

    if start_idx > stop_idx:
      print('PLOT WARNING: Galak aneh kau nih madakki start_idx > stop_idx, jadi kuatur be stop_idx += stop_idx - start_idx')
      stop_idx += stop_idx - start_idx

    if stop_idx - start_idx < 2:
      print('PLOT WARNING: Galak aneh kau nih madakki cuman ngeplot 2 titik!, kutambahin dikit')
      stop_idx += stop_idx - start_idx

    second = self.signal_arr[:,0][start_idx:stop_idx+1] # array seconds, tambah 1 biar dak indeks error
    amplitude = self.signal_arr[:,1][start_idx:stop_idx+1]  # array amplitudo
    bound = self.signal_arr[:,3][start_idx:stop_idx+1] # array bound label
    wave = self.signal_arr[:,2][start_idx:stop_idx+1]  # array wave label

    # kasus perbatasan jika yang discope dak nyampe itu
    if bound[0] != 1:
      bound[0] = 1 # pasang onset
    if bound[-1] != 2:
      bound[-1] = 2 # pasang offset

    # ambek indeks onset samo indeks offset
    onset_indices, offset_indices =  np.where(bound == 1)[0], np.where(bound == 2)[0]
    offset_indices = np.concatenate((onset_indices[1:], [offset_indices[-1]])) # biar dak ngebug, ngebugnyo tuh ado region yang overlap kadang kalo perbatasan
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111) # ax1 adalah plot utama

    # Plot amplitude
    ax1.plot(np.arange(start_idx, stop_idx+1), amplitude, color='blue', linewidth=1)

    legend_added = set()
    for i in range(min(len(onset_indices), len(offset_indices))):
      onset = onset_indices[i]
      offset = offset_indices[i]
      wave_type = wave[onset]
      color, label = self.__display_label_map[wave_type]

      if label not in legend_added: # Jika legend label belum pernah ada ya labeli coy
        ax1.axvspan(onset+start_idx, offset+start_idx, color=color, alpha=0.4, label=label)
        legend_added.add(label)
      else:
        ax1.axvspan(onset+start_idx, offset+start_idx, color=color, alpha=0.4, label=None)

    # nampelke indeks di bawah
    ax1.set_xlabel("Indeks")
    ax1.set_xlim((start_idx, stop_idx))
    ax1_xticks = np.unique(np.linspace(start_idx, stop_idx, num=5, dtype=int))
    ax1.set_xticks(ax1_xticks) # pastikan indeks tuh tetampil integer coy
    ax2 = ax1.twiny() # ax2 untuk display x-axis di pocok

    # kasih grid
    ax1.grid(color='black', linewidth=0.35, alpha=0.35)

    # kasih label sumbu-y
    ax1.set_ylabel(self.field_unit, rotation=0)

    # Add legend
    # ax1.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.25), loc='upper center', ncol=len(self.__display_label_map))
    ax1.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.29, -0.05), loc='lower right')

    # nampelke detik di pocok
    ax2.set_xlabel('Detik')
    ax2.set_xlim(ax1.get_xlim())
    ax2.set_xticks(ax1_xticks)
    ax2.set_xticklabels(np.round(second[ax1_xticks - start_idx], 3))

    # ngasih judul
    # plt.title(self.record_name)

    # List of notes (metadata)
    notes_list = [
      f"Sumber DB        : {self.source}",
      f"Nama Rekor       : {self.record_name}",
      f"Nama Sinyal      : {self.sig_name}",
      f"Sample Frekuensi : {self.fs}hz",
      f"Nama Anotasi     : {self.extension}"
      # Add more notes as needed
    ]

    code_font = FontProperties(family='monospace', style='normal', variant='normal', size=8)
    # Displaying notes on the right side of the plot
    for i, note in enumerate(notes_list):
      plt.text(1.05, 0.95 - i * 0.1, note, transform=ax1.transAxes, fontsize=10, va='top', ha='left', fontproperties=code_font)

    plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.5)

    # Show the plot
    plt.show()

  def get_beat(self, index):
    # Pertama, ambil dua indeks p_onset yang bertetangga, kemudian dapatkan simbol yang sesuai dengan p_onset yang sudah di persempit scopenya.
    p_onset_index_start = self.__get_nearest_p_onset_index(index)
    p_onset_index_end = self.__get_nearest_p_onset_index(index+1)
    new_ann_symbol = self.ann_symbol[p_onset_index_start:p_onset_index_end]

    # Kedua, ambil indeks annotasi dari p_onset awal ke p_onset akhir, kemudian mundur sebesar 40ms, kemudian ambil selisihnya antara mundur dan aktual
    new_ann_sample = self.ann_sample[p_onset_index_start:p_onset_index_end]
    new_ann_sample_rewinded = self.__rewind_arr_to_40ms(new_ann_sample)
    delta = new_ann_sample[0] - new_ann_sample_rewinded[0]

    # Ketiga, mendapatkan indeks anotasi relatif yang terbaru yang mana dimulai dari 0.
    relative_new_ann_sample = (new_ann_sample_rewinded - new_ann_sample_rewinded[0]) + delta
    signal_sample = self.signal_sample[new_ann_sample_rewinded[0] : new_ann_sample[-1] + delta + 1] # tambah 1 biar match antara awal dan akhir
    sec_start = self.signal_arr[new_ann_sample_rewinded[0], 0]

    return SinyalEKG(signal_sample, ann_fs=self.fs, ann_sample=relative_new_ann_sample, ann_symbol=new_ann_symbol[:len(relative_new_ann_sample)], sec_start=sec_start,
                     field_unit=self.field_unit,
                     source=self.source,
                     record_name=self.record_name,
                     sig_name=self.sig_name,
                     extension=self.extension)

  def get_valid_beat(self, index):
    '''
    remove outlier beat...
    '''
    p_onset_index_start = self.__get_nearest_p_onset_index(index)
    p_onset_index_end = self.__get_nearest_p_onset_index(index+1)

    new_ann_symbol = self.ann_symbol[p_onset_index_start:p_onset_index_end]
    # print(new_ann_symbol)
    if ''.join(new_ann_symbol) == '(p)(N)(t)':
      '''
      Beat yang valid adalah memiliki tepat:
      sebuah p-onset
      sebuah p-peak
      sebuah p-offset
      sebuah N-onset
      sebuah N-peak
      sebuah N-offset
      sebuah t-onset
      sebuah t-peak
      sebuah t-offset
      '''
      return self.get_beat(index)
    else:
      print('warning, invalid beat (outlier) di beat indeks:', index)
      return None

  def get_padded_beat(self, index, target_length=512, pad_iso=False, pad_bound=False):
    valid_beat = self.get_valid_beat(index)
    if valid_beat is None:
      return None

    signal_arr = np.zeros((target_length, 4), dtype=np.float64)

    original_amplitude = np.copy(valid_beat.signal_arr[:,1])

    signal_arr[:,1], pad_left = self.__pad_array(original_amplitude, target_length)
    sec_start = valid_beat.signal_arr[0,0] -  (pad_left/valid_beat.fs) # catat detik mulai

    # re-center padded_arr, INI PENTING BIAR DAK DRASTIS PERBATASAN PADDINGNYO
    if pad_bound:
      signal_arr[:,1][pad_left:pad_left+original_amplitude.shape[0]] = original_amplitude - (original_amplitude[0] + original_amplitude[-1]) / 2 # AMBEK RATO RATO

    signal_arr[:,2], _ = self.__pad_array(valid_beat.signal_arr[:,2], target_length)
    signal_arr[:,3], _ = self.__pad_array(valid_beat.signal_arr[:,3], target_length)

    if pad_iso:
      # ISOELECTRIC JUGO DIBUAT JADI BASELINE
      idx_for_zero = np.where(signal_arr[:,2] == 0)[0]
      signal_arr[:,1][idx_for_zero] = 0

    # Overwrite signal_arr
    valid_beat.signal_arr = signal_arr

    # Overwrite kolom waktu (signal_arr[:,0])
    valid_beat.__isi_kolom_waktu(start=sec_start)
    return valid_beat


#Muhammad Ikhwan Perwira.Sorry, but what is this? The user posted 30 lines of code. And you are posting like 100 lines of code. Only for filtering the character v?

#Muhammad Ikhwan Perwira. This is a little bit not what I wanted.

Sorry that code might not answer your question yet, the code is part of my current project. Perhaps it's useful for you. I noticed you need V annotation. You can replace N with V at self.__label_map.
